# Kubernetes tries to schedule on old node

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I have a k3s (v1.27.4+k3s1) Kubernetes cluster on Hetzner (deployed using https://github.com/kube-hetzner/terraform-hcloud-kube-hetzner) and I created new nodes with better hardware and joined them to the cluster, then I cordoned, drained and shutdown the old nodes, but some of the pods still want to schedule on the old node even though they are not in the cluster anymore (error nodeinfo not found for node name "agent-cx21-fsn1-iof"). I tried deleting HelmRelease but when Flux recreates it, it's still trying to schedule on the old node. Not sure how to diagnose further, any tips?

Pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
status:
  phase: Pending
  conditions:
    - type: PodScheduled
      status: 'False'
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2023-09-05T13:47:11Z'
      reason: SchedulerError
      message: nodeinfo not found for node name "vpl-agent-cx21-fsn1-iof"
  qosClass: Burstable
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: config
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: config-pgadmin-0
    - name: kube-api-access-zk8jq
      projected:
        sources:
          - serviceAccountToken:
              expirationSeconds: 3607
              path: token
          - configMap:
              name: kube-root-ca.crt
              items:
                - key: ca.crt
                  path: ca.crt
          - downwardAPI:
              items:
                - path: namespace
                  fieldRef:
                    apiVersion: v1
                    fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        defaultMode: 420
  containers:
    - name: pgadmin
      image: docker.io/dpage/pgadmin4:7
      ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: pgadmin-secret
      env:
        - name: PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT
          value: '8080'
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 10m
          memory: 128Mi
      volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /var/lib/pgadmin
        - name: kube-api-access-zk8jq
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /misc/ping
          port: 8080
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 3
        timeoutSeconds: 1
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 3
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /misc/ping
          port: 8080
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 3
        timeoutSeconds: 1
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 3
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  restartPolicy: Always
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  serviceAccountName: default
  serviceAccount: default
  automountServiceAccountToken: true
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 5050
    runAsGroup: 5050
    supplementalGroups:
      - 44
      - 109
      - 100
    fsGroup: 5050
    fsGroupChangePolicy: OnRootMismatch
  hostname: pgadmin-0
  subdomain: pgadmin
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  tolerations:
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoExecute
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoExecute
      tolerationSeconds: 300
  priority: 0
  enableServiceLinks: true
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (node died) and noticed that the previous deployments had some pvc(s) that were not deleted when the node was removed and the deployments uninstalled. After removing the pvc(s) the deployment came up on a different node correctly.

Comment: You might lose data if you delete pvc:s.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).